# How can I use the spacebar to trigger the ComboBox dropdown to show and allow selection within it using up and down arrow keys?

Tags: javafx

This code snippet below is something ChatGPT helped me put together.  Once I figure out how to alter the behavior of the CheckBoxTableCell column, I am going to extend the functionality of the existing TableView class by making it a little more spreadsheet like in that I can navigate around using arrow keys and interact with the different column types much like Excel allows...  The ComboBoxTableCell is where I am stuck on now... I am also fairly new to JavaFX so any guidance would also be appreciated!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class TableViewExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        ObservableList<Item> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Item(true, "Text 1", "Choice 1", "Custom Cell 1"),
                new Item(false, "Text 2", "Choice 2", "Custom Cell 2"),
                new Item(true, "Text 3", "Choice 3", "Custom Cell 3")
        );

        // Create CheckBox column
        TableColumn<Item, Boolean> checkBoxColumn = new TableColumn<>("Check");
        checkBoxColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().checkedProperty());
        checkBoxColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkBoxColumn));
        checkBoxColumn.setEditable(true);

        // Create TextField column
        TableColumn<Item, String> textFieldColumn = new TableColumn<>("Text Field");
        textFieldColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().textProperty());
        textFieldColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        textFieldColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
            event.getRowValue().setText(event.getNewValue());
        });

        // Create ComboBox column
        TableColumn<Item, String> comboBoxColumn = new TableColumn<>("Dropdown");
        comboBoxColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().choiceProperty());
        comboBoxColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(
                new StringConverter<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String toString(String object) {
                        return object;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String fromString(String string) {
                        return string;
                    }
                },
                "Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3"
        ));

        // Create a custom cell column
        TableColumn<Item, String> customCellColumn = new TableColumn<>("Custom Cell");
        customCellColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().customCellProperty());

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(checkBoxColumn, textFieldColumn, comboBoxColumn, customCellColumn);
        tableView.setItems(data);

        // Enable navigating with arrow keys
        tableView.setEditable(true);

        // Single-click edit mode for all columns
        tableView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 1) {
                tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), checkBoxColumn);
                tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), textFieldColumn);
                tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), comboBoxColumn);
                tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), customCellColumn);
            }
        });

        // Commit on focus change
        tableView.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            tableView.edit(-1, null);
        });

        // Handle CheckBox and ComboBox interaction
        tableView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                TableColumn<?, ?> focusedColumn = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell().getTableColumn();
                if (focusedColumn == checkBoxColumn) {
                    Item item = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    event.consume();
                } else if (focusedColumn == comboBoxColumn) {
                    System.out.println("ComboBoxFocused");
//**********************************************************************//
//I AM ABLE TO HIT SPACE BAR AND SEE THE OUTPUT "ComboBoxFocused"... I just can't seem to get //"inside" the combobox to move around inside with up and down arrow keys to select an option.  //What am I missing?
                  
                // ComboBoxCell does not start editing automatically, so we do it manually
                tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getFocusedIndex(), comboBoxColumn);
                comboBoxColumn.setOnEditStart(comboBoxEditEvent -> {
                    ComboBoxTableCell<Item, String> cell = (ComboBoxTableCell<Item, String>) comboBoxColumn.getCellFactory().call(comboBoxColumn);

                    // 3. Access the ChoiceBox within the ComboBoxTableCell
                    ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = (ChoiceBox<String>) cell.getGraphic();
                    if (choiceBox != null) {
                        System.out.println("Choicebox isn't null here..");
                        // You can interact with the choiceBox
                        choiceBox.show(); // For example, programmatically open the dropdown
                    }
 
                });
            }
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                TableColumn<?, ?> focusedColumn = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell().getTableColumn();
                if (focusedColumn == comboBoxColumn) {
                    ComboBoxTableCell<?, String> cell = (ComboBoxTableCell<?, String>) comboBoxColumn.getCellFactory().call(comboBoxColumn);
                    cell.commitEdit(cell.getItem());
                    tableView.requestFocus();
                    event.consume();
                }
            }
        });

        // Handle arrow key navigation and start ComboBox cell editing
        tableView.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode().isArrowKey()) {
                if (tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell().getTableColumn() == comboBoxColumn) {
                    // Open the ComboBox when navigating to the ComboBox column
                    tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), comboBoxColumn);
                }
            }
        });

        // Open the ComboBox when entering edit mode
       



        VBox root = new VBox(tableView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX TableView Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final SimpleBooleanProperty checked;
        private final SimpleStringProperty text;
        private final SimpleStringProperty choice;
        private final SimpleStringProperty customCell;

        public Item(boolean checked, String text, String choice, String customCell) {
            this.checked = new SimpleBooleanProperty(checked);
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
            this.choice = new SimpleStringProperty(choice);
            this.customCell = new SimpleStringProperty(customCell);
        }

        public SimpleBooleanProperty checkedProperty() {
            return checked;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked.get();
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            this.checked.set(checked);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty textProperty() {
            return text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.set(text);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty choiceProperty() {
            return choice;
        }

        public String getChoice() {
            return choice.get();
        }

        public void setChoice(String choice) {
            this.choice.set(choice);
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty customCellProperty() {
            return customCell;
        }

        public String getCustomCell() {
            return customCell.get();
        }

        public void setCustomCell(String customCell) {
            this.customCell.set(customCell);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

Use a key listener on your node.

**Solution**

```
setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.X) { 
        System.out.println("impl functionality");
    }
});
```

**Note**

It might be a better idea to use `setOnKeyReleased()`.